# A difficulty in understanding the solution of Q.44 Math Subject GRE 0568 exam .

Tags: probability, gre-exam

The question and its answer is given in the following picture:[image]

I do not understand why in the answer the writer exclude letter(A), could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: so for A to hold, you must have 50 heads, doesn't matter what order, just 50 heads exactly. So you must also have 50 tails exactly. You can work out the probability of this happening using probability trees or combinatorics -- = (100 choose 50) * 1/2^100 ~ 0.08. If in doubt revert to more basic mathematics.

Comment: I'm confused by something else. How is $D$ equivalent to $48 \le H \le 52$?? It says $H \le 48$.

Comment: @mdave16 no. $H \le 48$ implies $T \ge 48$ already since $H+T = 100$. I'm confused why it says and $T \ge 48$.

Comment: I think D must be a typo.  If $H \le 48$ then $T \ge 52$ so $T \ge 48$ is redundant.  I think is is supposed to be $H \ge 48$ and $T \ge 48$.

Comment: The rationale to exclude A.  While exactly $50$ is more likely than exactly any other number.  As the number of flips gets to be large,  exactly 50 becomes increasingly small.  It is more likely than some of the options provided happening nearly 8% of the time.  That is still much less than the 38% that is D.

Comment: @Fleablood  I think that is the "trick" of the question.  The less than careful reader dismisses that answer because it seems too specific, when really half the information is irrelevant.

Comment: @fleablood reading the answer, it looks like the answerer has interpreted $48\le H\le 52$ what is interesting is that $H\le 48$ is very nearly the same  probability.

Comment: @DougM But I don't see how $H \le 48$ is equivalent to $48 \le H \le 52$.  So I suspect a typo.

Comment: @fleablood either the question is wrong or the rationale is wrong.  I am inclined to say it is the rationale that is wrong.

Comment: Is being within 1/2 a standard deviation of the mean, the same as being over hallf a standard deviation below the mean?  If so they are equivalent.

Comment: @DougM  I do not understand what do you mean by the rationale ? also your point of view is not so clear for me.